# Vundle for VIM is not working on Ubuntu

Tags: plugins, vim, vim-plugin

I installed Vundle via the instructions given at this blog http://web.archive.org/web/20120731003342/http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/sane-vim-plugin-management

but when trying to run `:BundleInstall` I get a VIM error

```
E492: Not an editor command: BundleInstall
```

Here is my `tree ~/.vim`

```
/home/max/.vim
└── bundle
    └── vundle
        ├── autoload
        │   ├── vundle
        │   │   ├── config.vim
        │   │   ├── installer.vim
        │   │   └── scripts.vim
        │   └── vundle.vim
        ├── doc
        │   └── vundle.txt
        ├── LICENSE-MIT.txt
        ├── README.md
        └── test
            ├── files
            │   └── test.erl
            ├── minirc.vim
            └── vimrc
```

Also when starting up VIM I get a slew of `E492`s like so

```
Error detected while processing /home/max/.vimrc:
line    6:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#rc
line   10:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
line   15:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
line   16:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
line   17:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
line   19:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'surround.vim'
line   20:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'snipMate'
line   21:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'tComment'
line   22:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'mru.vim'
line   23:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'The NERD tree'
line   24:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'matchit.zip'
line   25:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'Vimball'
line   26:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'ScrollColors'
line   27:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'L9'
line   28:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'FuzzyFinder'
line   30:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
```

And here is my `.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible

filetype off  " required!

set rtp+=~/.vim/vundle.git/ 
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required! 
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

" My Bundles here:
"
" original repos on github
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
Bundle 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" vim-scripts repos
Bundle 'surround.vim'
Bundle 'snipMate'
Bundle 'tComment'
Bundle 'mru.vim'
Bundle 'The NERD tree'
Bundle 'matchit.zip'
Bundle 'Vimball'
Bundle 'ScrollColors'
Bundle 'L9'
Bundle 'FuzzyFinder'
" non github repos
Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'


" Shortcuts


noremap <C-Up> <C-W>+
noremap <C-Down> <C-W>-
noremap <C-Left> <C-W>>
noremap <C-Right> <C-W><

nnoremap ,v <C-w>v
nnoremap ,h <C-w>s
nnoremap ,, <C-w>w

map <F11> <Esc>:call libcallnr("gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)<CR> 
nmap gf <S-g>
nmap f :FufFile <CR>
vmap c gc 
nmap c gcc
nmap tt :tabnew <CR>
nmap tc :tabclose <CR>
nmap ml :MRU <CR>
nmap s :w <CR>
nmap q :q! <CR>
syntax on
set mouse=a "enables mouse

" Selecting different color schemes
map <silent> ,3 :NEXTCOLOR<cr>
map <silent> ,2 :PREVCOLOR<cr>
map <silent> ,1 :SCROLL<cr>

" Directory Set up

set backup "backs up files
set backupdir=$HOME/.vimbackup
set directory=$HOME/.vimswap
set viewdir=$HOME/.vimviews
"
" silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vimbackup'
" silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vimswap'
" silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vimviews'

" au BufWinLeave * silent! mkview "makes vim save view state
" au BufWinEnter * silent! loadview "makes vim load view state

" Appearance

set columns=60

set guifont=Monaco:h11

map <F11> <Esc>:call libcallnr("gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)<CR>
map <silent> ,m :e ftp://mitemiu.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/Mitemiu/<CR>
" map <silent> ,c :e ftp://www.caeious.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/caeious/<CR>
map <silent> ,c :e ftp://www.caeious.com/public_html/<CR>


color jellybeans
set tabpagemax=10 "show only 10 tabs
set background=dark

set number

set scrolloff=3 "minimum lines to keep above/below cursor
set foldenable "auto fold code

" Behaviour
" set nowrap "wrap long lines
set linebreak
:filetype plugin indent on  " lets filetype plugins be used

" if bufwinnr(1)
"   map <kPlus><C-W>+
"   map <kMinus><C-W>-  
"   map <kDivide><c-w><
"   map <kMultiply><c-w>>
" endif

set autoindent
set smartindent                                
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set spell

set showmatch "shows matching parens, brackets

set winminheight=0

set go-=T "eliminates tool bar in gVim
set go-=m "eliminates menu bar in gVim
set go-=r "eliminates right scroll bar
set lines=50 "50 lines of text instead of 24

set backspace=2 "makes backspace work like normally it does
:fixdel

set vb t_vb= "prevents vim from beeping when command is bad. instead it flashes screen.            

set ruler "shows statusline, displays curor position

set incsearch "vim searches text as you enter it
" set hlsearch "hilights searched items
set ignorecase "case insensitive search
set smartcase "case sensetive when using captials
set wildmenu "shows list instead of completing
set wildmode=list:longest,full "command <TAB> completeiton, lists matches,
set virtualedit=all "lets cursor freely roam anywhere like in command mode
```

Obviously Vundle has not been installed properly. **How do I make Vundle work?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Vundle is installed in

```
~/.vim/bundle/vundle
```

so this line

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/vundle.git/
```

should be

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle
```

---

```
~/.vim/vundle.git/
```

is the path of a folder containing everything that makes a Git repository a Git repository. You can't really expect Vim to find usable scripts there.

Comment: Well, you actually didn't follow the instructions as the correct line is given at step two. Why did you change it?

Comment: actually I was wrong. I was first following another tutorial http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/sane-vim-plugin-management/ and had assumed it was an exact copy of gmarik's. I will correct it in my post.

Comment: Also, this .vimrc worked well for me: https://github.com/wavded/vim-stylus/issues/26#issuecomment-13114948

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem using `git commit` or `crontab -e`

These commands seemed to invoke `vi` instead of `vim`

setting this in my .bashrc fixed this

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

Comment: Thanks, i met this problem too, and fixed by `git config --global core.editor vim`

Answer (score 2):

I just met the problem and I resolved it after reading

https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/issues/168

It says.

This might happen if you call the vi editor explicitly (to avoid any aliases) by /usr/bin/vi instead of vim.
A plain "git commit" would do this for me before I configured it to use vim instead. (git config --global core.editor "vim")

Comment: Exactly my issue. Did not get errors when calling vim directly but only when calling git commit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. After tried all the methods mentioned recommended by others and failed. 
Finally, I found that on our Ubuntu 14.04.1 service, VIM is not installed as default!

It is hard to realize this problem, since VIM users like me just used to type "vi" instead of "vim", and it shows a "VIM - improved VI" welcome page.

So make sure you have installed VIM:

```
whereis vim
```

Or just type:

```
vim
```

If it is not installed, do as it recommends:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Answer (score 1):

vi ~/.gitconfig

and

```
[core]

 autocrlf = false
```

set

```
[core]

 autocrlf = true
```

then $rm -rf ~/.vim/bundle/vundle

and $git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git ~/.vim/bundle/vundle

Comment: My problem didn't involve the `~/.gitconfig`, but removing the bundle and reinstalling it again made the problem go away, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

as @romainl said my vundle installed in `.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/`, so you need to change line :
`set rtp+=~/.vim/vundle.git/`

to 
`set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/`

yeah thank you ~

Answer (score 0):

The .vimrc here worked for me: https://github.com/wavded/vim-stylus/issues/26#issuecomment-13114948

Comment: I'd send the original link (it was posted on a blog) but I can't for the life of me find it : (