# E492: Not an editor command: TlistToggle

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, cscope, taglist

I am using Vim with cscope, ctags and TagList. 
When I open a file with just using vim. I am able to use TagList but when I open a file using cscope, there comes error as:

```
Error detected while processing /gauravg/.vimrc:
line    9:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
line   13:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'plugin/taglist.vim'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Below is my .vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required!
Bundle 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
call vundle#end()
"Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
"Plugin 'steffanc/cscopemaps.vim'
Plugin 'plugin/taglist.vim'
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you install `vundle`?

Comment: Make sure `$EDITOR` and/or `$CSCOPE_EDITOR` point to the right Vim.

Comment: EDITOR and CSCOPE_EDITOR is not set

Comment: See the related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12179655/714955 And make sure VIM is installed! http://stackoverflow.com/a/39049319/714955

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Plugin` instead of `Bundle` for:

```
Bundle 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
```

Also, all of your plugins must be added **before**:

```
call vundle#end()
```

See the [Quick Start](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start) of Vundle for more information.

This `.vimrc` should work:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required!
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
"Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
"Plugin 'steffanc/cscopemaps.vim'
Plugin 'plugin/taglist.vim'
" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: I have again installed vundle and changed the Bundle to Plugin, but nothing changed. The error msgs are same except in place of Bundle it is showing Plugin.

Comment: Then are the files under `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` correct? Have you done `git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/plugged/Vundle.vim`, or is it something else? If it's a git repository and points to `https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim`, what happens after you run `git pull` under `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` and open a new Vim session?

Comment: There are files under `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`. I have cloned from the given github url. As I have already mentioned in the origin issue that plugin related issue is only reflected when I open any file via **cscope**, If I open it via vim editor, everything is OK and I am not getting any error.